# Injecting Ninject into a Processor for Object Resolution in Mediator Pattern Implementation

Tags: c#, ninject, heap-memory

I'm having a memory leak problem which I can't figure out a plug for. It is for a desktop application, not web, so the life of objects is longer than a single request.

I'm trying to implement the architecture described in this excellent blog post - https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

The **QueryProcessor** class requires a IOC container, because it resolves a concrete type when the **Process** method is called. My implementation looks like this:

```
public sealed class QueryProcessor : IQueryProcessor, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IKernel _container;
    private bool _disposed;

    public QueryProcessor(IKernel container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    public TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        dynamic handler = (_container.Target as IKernel).Get(handlerType);

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !_disposed)
        {
            // dispose container ???
            _disposed = true;
        }            
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that if I inject the Ninject kernel, it means the **QueryProcessor** class does not get garbage collected when it goes out of scope, as it maintains a reference to the kernel.

If I dipose of it, and call Dispose on the kernel, I've killed my kernel and there no more DI for the app.

If I create a separate kernel and inject it for each instance of the QueryProcessor, then Ninject chucks an exception as soon as it tries to resolve a concrete type - *“Error loading Ninject component ICache”*. Apparently Ninject does not like more than 1 kernel.

Is there any way a class can have a member and release that member before it gets garbage collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I am having is that if I inject the Ninject kernel, it
>   means the QueryProcessor class does not get garbage collected when it
>   goes out of scope, as it maintains a reference to the kernel.

The object is eligible for garbage collection when nothing is referencing this object. It doesn't matter what other objects this objects references. So maybe you are looking for memory leak in the wrong place. I see that you are not registering for any event's of IKernel (this would create a reference from IKernels delegate to your object) so if nothing else is referencing your QueryProcessor it should be garbage collected.

Comment: OK. I'll do an experiment or two to see if the kernel is not the culprit. Good suggestion. I'll use a process of elimination to figure it out.

Comment: You were quite right. And I'm glad that's the case, as my understanding of reachable objects aligned with your explanation. So I was very confused by my supposition that the kernel was to blame. There was a long and complicated path which was keeping the object alive. It came about somewhere that I was trying to be a bit fancy and got caught out. Thanks.